# How to add apk from URL in capabilities?

Tags: appium, remotewebdriver

I am trying to reference apk from url but not successful. Here is what I am trying -

```
capabilities.setCapability("app", new URL("http://jenkinsserverurl:8181/job/projectname/apk/apkname.apk"));
.
.
.
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://remote test url:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);

Appium server throws following error :-
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"app":{"userInfo":null,"query":null,"hCode":1439549959,"defaultPort":80,"path":"//.apk","protocol":"http","ref":null,"file":"//.apk","port":8181,"authority":":8181","host":"","class":"java.net.URL"},"appPackage":"","appActivity":".MainActivity","browserName":"","platformName":"Android","version":"4.4","deviceName":"emulator-5554","platform":"ANDROID"}}
error: Using local app, but didn't end in .zip, .ipa or .apk
```

Suggestions???

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
File appDir = new File("/home/user/..."); //only path to apk file directory
File app = new File(appDir, "app.apk");
capabilities.setCapability("app",app.getAbsolutePath());
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.packageName");
driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

---

**Where:**

**app** :

The absolute local path or remote http URL to an .ipa or .apk file, or a .zip containing one of these. Appium will attempt to install this app binary on the appropriate device first. Note that this capability is not required for Android if you specify appPackage and appActivity capabilities. Incompatible with browserName.

Also if you want to use remote driver only you can cast it with Android driver like this -

```
driver = (AndroidDriver) new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),
            capabilities);
```

Otherwise use AndroidDriver.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is bceause of you are not using "MobileCapabilityType"

For install apk from url :

```
String url = "http://example.com/myapp.apk";  
 
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, url);
```

For install from file :

```
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(URL, File) //download file

File appDir = new File(userDir, fileName); //set file

capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, appDir.getAbsolutePath());
```